# DVD (vob file) to online video viewer?

Tags: dvd, flash, website, html5

I've been sent a DVD which needs to be put onto a website, but I honestly don't even know where to start.

Do I simply convert the file using some software to MP4(?!) and then use something like http://videojs.com/ to view it online?

I'm really sorry for the vague question, but I want to produce the best quality results, with good compression, good quality and a nice video player interface. Would really appreciate any recommendations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the process you will go through is:

1. rip the DVD to a compressed format
2. upload the ripped video to your web server
3. code html to embed the video on your web page (linking to the ripped video)

A good ripping tool to start with is http://www.labdv.com/dvdx/ which lets you easily convert your DVD files into .avi or .mpeg or .mp4

Once you have a ripped video file, upload it to your webserver

Your website html needs to have embed code to show the video:
(we'll assume you've named the file 'video.avi' and placed in a folder named 'media')

```
<embed src="media/video.avi" height="200" width="320"/>
```

An alternative would be to rip the DVD using DVDx, upload it to youtube, get the youtube video embed code and then paste this into your website html

This method simply removes the need for you to upload the ripped video to your own webserver and use youtubes servers instead :-)

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! They don't want it hosted on YouTube so I'll go with the first option. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I noticed after re-reading you're also interested in implementing html5 webpages - in this case you can try using this html5 only code

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
       <source src="media/video.avi" type="video/avi" />
    <embed src="media/video.avi" width="320" height="240" />
    </video>
```

The video tag is an html5 tag that gives you nice play/stop etc. controls (by setting controls='controls')-

adding the embed tag is simply a safety net for browsers which do not support html5 i.e. if video tag is unsupported then use embed instead

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 to be more than just the spec that the W3C validator checks your document against. Part of [html5 media player](http://html5socket.com/)involves standards for bolt on technology including web workers, CSS3, server sent events, etc. that are going to (I hope) revolutionize the web and do away with the need for 3rd party browser plugins